# Don't have Click event in TextBox in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, events, textbox, click

I just want to add simple thing, wherever i click on TextBox I want to delete text that is inside. The thing is I DON'T have in list of events, event called Click.. Is this even possible? Or just I need to install some add on. Buttons are fine, they have Click event.

Answer (score 1):

`MouseButtonLeftUp` would work if you only are concerned with mouse clicks. With that said, what if someone tabs into the box or focus is entered by other means?

At that point you may want to look at the `GotFocus` event. Any time the `TextBox` receives focus, you can handle the event.

Answer (score 0):

TextBox has events called MouseLeftButtonUp and MouseLeftButtonDown, you can use them.